# Typescript error argument of type {} is not assignable to parameter of type User | User () => User

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks, use-state

Checked other stackoverflow posts regarding this error and I still dont get it. This block of code is getting the error.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({})
```

I mapping over card component that needs the props from the user data. Why isn't this working?

Also i have a home page that grabs all the user with this block of code and i dont get the type error.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([])
```

Why am i not getting such error on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, your object is missing the required properties or is not `instanceof User`.

In your 2nd example, thats just an empty array so that will work. In that case, `User` describes the type requirement for the items.

Comment: got ya thanks a bunch

Comment: I didnt know i had to add all the props into the object. I thought by adding <Employee> it automatically infers it